# Problems with recursive formula

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to do a recursion for my coding class in C language. For some reason, the solution that I get is wrong, event though I made sure multiple times that the formula is correct.

[image]

This is what I am supposed to replicate in code.

```
double recursion(int n, int k, int flag, int subN, int rep)
{
    if(rep == 0)
        return 0;
    if(flag == 0)
        return sqrt(n/subN+recursion(n, ++k, ++flag, subN-2, --rep));
    else
        return sqrt(k/subN+recursion(--n, k, --flag, subN-2, --rep));
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%f", recursion(n, 0, 0, 2*n, n));

    return 0;
}
```

For n = 6, I get 1.021897, for n = 7, I get 1.005430

My solution:

- n - the number we are starting from, user inputs this number in
  console
- k - this integer is supposed to be that counter from 1
- subN - this is the number we are dividing n with
- rep - acts as a counter to know when the recursion should stop (it always ends after n cycles)

Comment: `rekurzija` and `recursion` are named differently. Maybe you forgot to change the names while uploading the snippet?

Comment: Don't us x++ and --i when you are not saving the variable, just    call sqrt(k/subN+rekurzija(n-1, k, flag-1, subN-2, rep-1));

Comment: @wookiekim I did, thanks, but that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing two `int` you get integer division, where the answer is an integer. Replace at least one of the operands with a double to get floating-point calculations.

```
double recursion(int n, int k, int flag, int subN, int rep)
{
    if(rep == 0)
        return 0;
    if(flag == 0)
        return sqrt((double)n/subN+recursion(n, k+1, flag+1, subN-2, rep-1));
    else
        return sqrt((double)k/subN+recursion(n-1, k, flag-1, subN-2, rep-1));
}
```

or even better just change the function signature to
`double recursion(double n, double k, int flag, double subN, int rep)`

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Comment: This signature will also do the same: `double recursion(double n, double k, int flag, double subN, int rep)`

Comment: @Simson I would suggest that solution instead. It makes the function's meaning more explicit.

Comment: @JL2210 I also think that would be better but at that time the answer was already accepted so I did not bother to edit it ;-)